# Angular app is rewriting links strangely

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've been working on an angular 1.x application with some other people, and suddenly my navigation links aren't working, but only on my home machine! I don't know what went wrong, but I'm very confused.

So, I have an anchor tag like `<a href=/#/foo>My Fancy Link</a>` and I expect that to end up at a url like `http://localhost/#/foo`.

But when I start the application, I redirects to `http://localhost/#!/`. The `$location` service seems to work ok and directs me to `http://localhost/#!/bar` and that's ok. But when I click on the link, the url is rewritten as `http://localhost/#!/#%2Ffoo`. I expect it to be `http://localhost/#/foo`.

Any idea why this is happening and how I can fix it?

**Notes**

```
package.json

{
  "name": "my-fancy-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "karma start karma.conf.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.5.8",
    "angular-mocks": "^1.5.8",
    "angular-route": "^1.5.8",
    "angular-sanitize": "^1.5.8",
    "angular-smart-table": "^2.1.8",
    "angular-ui-tree": "^2.22.1",
   "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "i18next": "^4.0.0",
    "i18next-xhr-backend": "^1.2.1",
    "jasmine": "^2.5.2",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "^1.1.0",
    "ng-i18next": "^1.0.4",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "2.1.7"
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you using `ui-router`?

Comment: No, I've attached my dependencies as a note.